# Is it possible to create a non CQL based Solr core in DataStax Enterprise?

Tags: solr, datastax, cql, datastax-enterprise

The DataStax website says that:

> You cannot create a Solr core unless you first upload the schema and configuration files. If you are creating a CQL-based Solr core, the table must exist in Cassandra before creating the core".

Is there a way to create a non CQL based Solr core, possibly using Solr's HTTP API?

Comment: For reference I have found this in a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619947/create-new-cores-in-solr-via-http?rq=1

Comment: Doesn't the example on the page you copied that from show how you can do it with the regular HTTP API? [DSE Creating a Solr core](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchCreatCore.html) and the `curl` example command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like a normal Solr core, not using any integration with Cassandra side?

I cannot double check right now, but I am pretty sure I did this once in the past. If you start off a CQL based core, you just need to remove any mention of DSE custom stuff in solrconfig.xml (there are several custom classes being used instead of Solr ones, replace them with their vanilla Solr counterparts) and schema.xml (not sure if I had to change anything in there). Then use those modified files to create the new core. Give it a go